# Assembly arrays format 80X86 missread

Tags: arrays, assembly

I'm trying to create an array in 80X86 assembly but it looks like this

[image: assembly screen dump]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Fixed image and spelling errors

Comment: Your `Arr1 DB 123,2,65` line created an array already.  Did you have some other problem?  Just guessing, but you probably got something wrong with `Arr3` having 16-bit elements and the other two having 8-bit elements.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong within your picture. I'm not even sure what you mean by *"assembly arrays format"*, as there's no such thing as "array" in machine code. That high level programming language terminology like "variable" and "array" is being sometimes used within assembly tutorials, but it is a bit misleading, as the real thing is CPU + memory, and what kind of instructions you run on the CPU, that builds logical illusion of variable/array. On the HW level it's just computer memory bytes, or values in CPU registers, nothing more. Byte stored at `Arr1` adr has value `123` => check, OK.

Comment: If you want to see all three byte values of memory at address `Arr1`, you can probably adjust the formatting of things in "Variables" view (can't recall how, you don't even specify what that screenshot is from, I just guess turbo debugger), but I never did that in assembly, I simply use the memory view window to check memory content (used to do some basic formatting in C/C++ in VS debugger, like displaying certain variable in hexa, but in ASM the short code you write is often simple enough to read just from raw hexa byte values any information you want, without additional formatting).

Answer (score 1):

> What am I doing wrong?

The only thing that is wrong looking at the picture is the last instruction on the page.

`CMP Arr1[2-BX],AL` is an invalid instruction.

You can never subtract a register like that!

---

There's nothing wrong with the creation of the arrays. The *Variables* watch window is correctly showing the **first element** of each array. It does so in text form, decimal form, and hexadecimal form.